# vi mode in php interactive shell?

Tags: php, vim, editor, vi

I use php's interactive shell (`php -a`) to explore and debug a PHP code base. I am used to working in vi mode in shell programs (i.e. I have `set -o vi` in my .bashrc file). I have found no mention anywhere of an editor option for php's interactive shell, so I'm pessimistic, but can anyone tell me of a way to run `php -a` in vi mode? Thanks!

Comment: `php -a` is supposed to used readline so adding `set editing-mode vi` to your `~/.inputrc` *should* be enough. It doesn't work here, though.

Comment: [phpsh](http://www.phpsh.org/) is an alternative.